# Delete initial rows of a pandas dataframe that satisfy column value condition while keeping the sequence values in a column intact

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dt = {'id': [120,120,120,120,121,121,121], 'day': [0, 1,2,3,0,1,2], 'value': [[0.5,3.4,2.7],[0.45,3.4,0.7],[0.25,0.4,0.7],[0.15,0.34,0.17],[0.35,3.4,2.7],[0.5,3.44,2.57],[0.5,0.34,0.37]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dt)


    day id  value
0   0   120 [0.5, 3.4, 2.7]
1   1   120 [0.45, 3.4, 0.7]
2   2   120 [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
3   3   120 [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
4   0   121 [0.35, 3.4, 2.7]
5   1   121 [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
6   2   121 [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
```

I have a `pandas dataframe`. I want the sequence `column "day"` to be of **maximum value upto 1**. For `column day` with value above 1 I want to delete it's initial rows, and then reset the sequence to [0-1]

That is in this case, `column"id"=120` has **column "day"** has two extra values 2 and 3. I want to delete their first two rows in this case and then replace the column values of day to (0,1).

Result:

```
    day id  value
0   0   120 [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
1   1   120 [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
2   0   121 [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
3   1   121 [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract the max value when grouped by `id` and `query`

```
m = df.groupby('id').day.transform('max')
df.assign(day=df.day.sub(m - 1)).query('day >= 0')

   day   id               value
2    0  120    [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
3    1  120  [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
5    0  121   [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
6    1  121   [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can using `groupby` with `tail`, then we do `cumcount` recreate the day

```
df.groupby('id').tail(2).assign(day=lambda x : x.groupby('id').cumcount())
Out[221]: 
   day   id               value
2    0  120    [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
3    1  120  [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
5    0  121   [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
6    1  121   [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
```

Comment: Just a query, what if the column"id" does not  follow a sequence orde and has values in the order 0,2,0,1.

How do I keep the column"day" as it is when deleting

Comment: @JerryGeorge sort before groupby using df.sort_values('day')

Comment: Just a query, what if the days are not in a s

Comment: @JerryGeorge what you mean day a not in a s